# Service bindService vs LocalBroadcastManager

Tags: android, localbroadcastmanager, bindservice

I have multiple activities and a background always running service (see context [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36783792/service-that-always-run-on-office-hours)).

Which approach is better, use bindService() or app confined notifications using sendBroadcast() and a BroadcastReceiver in each activity?

Thanks

Comment: definitely `bindService` (using `bound local service` pattern)

Comment: Are your activities and the background always running service in the same process? Does your background always running service `exported` attribute has `false` value?

Comment: Not sure, I ended up doing something completely different